# htaccess: cache all images but exclude caching images from subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-expires

I want to cache all images for 1 month and it works great but the problem is when I try to exclude a subdirectory from caching.

So there are images on:

> / (base dir)
> /IMG/
> /IMG/folder/
> IMG/BIG/

so all images need to be cached, but i want to make it to not cache images that are on **IMG/BIG/** folder

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>  
  ExpiresActive on

  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

the above code works but when

i try this code to exclude /IMG/BIG then it doesn't work

```
<Directory "/IMG/BIG">

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires 0
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

I want to fix this in the .htaccess that is in the root folder and not by adding another .htaccess inside /IMG/big folder

Comment: Do you have anything else in `/IMG/BIG/` that you do want cached? When you say that "doesn't work", I assume you are getting a 500 Internal Server Error response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
> ```

*Aside:* The correct mime-type for JPEG files is `image/jpeg`, not `image/jpg`, so the above probably isn't doing anything.

The `<Directory>` directive is not permitted in `.htaccess` - this should have resulted in a 500 Internal Server Error (the details of which would be in your server's error log).

The `<IfModule>` wrappers are not required, unless you intend to use the same config on multiple servers where mod_expires and/or mod_headers are not enabled (unlikely).

To target everything else except the `/IMG/BIG` subdirectory then you can use an `<If>` expression and check against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable with a negated regex (`!~` operator). For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/IMG/BIG/#">
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
</If>
```

To specifically override any headers for requests to `/IMG/BIG/` then you could add an `<Else>` directive:

```
<Else>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires 0
    </FilesMatch>
</Else>
```

Unless there are other file types in the `/IMG/BIG/` directory that you might want cached then you could remove the `<FilesMatch>` container.